# Can you prove the following Cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let (An) be a Cauchy sequence such that n is a member of N, and let c be a member of R, prove that (c*An) is also a Cauchy sequence

Comment: In the definition take $N$ s.t. $|A_n-A_m|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$ when $n,m>N$ and the claim follow.

Comment: And if $c<0$ ???

Comment: @Fred: I just gave a comment, not an answer... The OP can adapt properly I'm sure ;-) By the way, in what your answer give something more than my comment ?

Answer (score 0):

If $c=0$, then we are done.

Let $c \ne 0$. Then

$|cA_n-cA_m|=|c||A_n-A_m| < \epsilon \iff |A_n-A_m|< \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$.

Can you procced ?

Comment: Does this not prove its a cauchy sequence, doesn't it satisfy the definition of a cauchy sequence?

Comment: If (A_n) is Cauchy and $ \epsilon >0$, then there is $N$ such that $|A_n-A_m|< \frac{\epsilon}{|c|}$ for all $n,m >N$. Hence we have $ |cA_n-cA_m|< \epsilon$ for all $n,m >N$, which shows that $(cA_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Thank you very much been struggling to get my head around this definition